# Trouble with auto import React component when using vscode 1.28

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

Recently I don't know why auto import suggestion doesn't work as it used to. For example I want to auto import  component, as I hit enter when the suggestion list appears, it only show this:

```
<import('./components/CourseList').CourseList
```

instead of  `<CourseList />` and import line

EDIT: after reinstall VSC 1.26 it works again but it doesn't work on 1.28

Comment: Hey Can you share the relevant code of the issue so that it will help us to help you with the fix

Comment: @Think-Twice it works on VSC 1.26 accross all projects but it doesn't in 1.28 so i think it's not my code problem but the latest VSC

Comment: Ok sorry I don't use Visual Studio Code so I don't have idea about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running into [this bug](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27317). It should be fixed early next week by VS Code 1.28.1.

As a workaround, upgrade the version of typescript that VS Code uses by following [these instructions](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/typescript#_using-newer-typescript-versions)